# Updating JCombobox gives always the first element EMPTY

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I have no choice to use this method, in order to update a `JCombobox`, which consists of:

```
update() {
    faultySection.removeAllItems();
    int idx = 1;
    faultySection.insertItemAt(select, 0);

    for (Incident i : listeIncidents) {
        faultySection.insertItemAt(object, idx++);
    }
}
```

But what i get is that the first element (default one) is still empty instead of being `select`.

[image: The default object is empty in the JCombobox]

[image: Have a look at the content of the list]

Comment: For better help sooner, post an SSCCE.

Comment: and with description whats your goal

Answer (score 2):

This looks functionally correct to me. Put a debugger breakpoint inside this method and monitor the state of the faultySection as it's processed. You can add it to a watch statement and it should make your job much easier. I think there has to be some other piece of code modifying it in another statement.

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
faultySection.insertItemAt("select", 0);
faultySection.setSelectedIndex(0);
```